# how to root Galaxy SL GT i9003 for DDLF2

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, samsung-galaxy-sl

I am running official Samsung ROM build version 2.6.3 DDLF2. I wish to root it for reverse tethering and few other utilities. Need a trusted link for rooting tutorial or a rooting package for the same.

Comment: The Answer provided by Chinmay is absolutely correct. Providing the direct link to a little more explanatory tutorial. [How to Root Galaxy SL DDLF2](http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/09/19/root-galaxy-sl-i9003-ddlf2-android-236-firmware/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device seems to be quite easy to root.

1. Make sure you have Samsung Kies installed.
2. Download [Odin 1.8.3](http://ul.to/o2xcp01n)
3. Go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1331253) and download the appropriate file for your firmware. To find out you firmware's version, you can run `dumpstate` on the phone (via `adb shell` or any terminal application). The fifth line of the output will contain the version identifier (like `Build: GINGERBREAD.XWKPG`).
4. Start your phone in download mode. Switch off your phone, and restart it while holding power + volume down + home
5. Enter download mode and plug your phone into your PC.
6. Start Odin and put the firmware you just downloaded into the PDA box.
7. Click Start. Your phone should reboot after a while.
8. Congratulations! You are now rooted!
9. Switch off your phone and reboot into Recovery by holding volume up + home + power.
10. Wipe Dalvik Cache.
11. Reboot.

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1894737)

Comment: thnx for the reply. However, I  have already gine with through thuis link. What confuses me is what's CFROOT in name DDLF2_CFROOT-05-07-2012.tar . is CF some other ROM?

Comment: CFRoot is a rooting package by ChainFire. The CFROOT in the name means that the ROM has CFRoot integrated.

Comment: Ok. Thnx. so it's safe to go for this ackage for rooting.

Comment: Note that it's never _completely_ safe to root. But in general, you should be fine.

Comment: is it necessary to wipe cache? I havent done that and it;s working fine for now.

Comment: Not wiping the cache can lead to weird bugs at times. I'd recommend that you do it anyway, as you won't lose any data.

Comment: Will this delete application data?

Comment: Just tested it: This will not delete any application data.

Answer (score -2):

The [BAM kernel v15 beta](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1355675) will root your device. Just flash it via Odin and that's it!!  There you will get everything what you need!

I own the same phone, and I feel it's safest way to root because some newbies flash some other packages which break their Wi-Fi or even cause the phone to boot loop.

Comment: Flashing a new kernel shouldn't be necessary to root....

Comment: @MatthewRead dude that is one of the ways how you can gain a root access.. please read the question carefully before giving such a rude comment. his question is "how to root Galaxy SL GT i9003 for DDLF2"
so flashing the above mentioned kernel is one of the way.. and it's probably best kernel around for that phone.. I have same phone.. so please if you don't know.. stop giving comments so rudely!

Comment: I know you *can* root via flashing a kernel that roots, I simply think it's overkill.  I don't see how that's rude.