# Recover data from bootlooped phone

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-sl

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Plus (GT-I9003) that is stuck in a boot loop. It is running the stock Samsung firmware (Android 2.3.5). I want to recover the data (specifically of the Memo application) from the device. I can boot into recovery mode and then connect via `adb shell`, but I'm not allowed to read `/data`:

```
$ ls -l /
(...)
drwxrwx--x root     root              1970-01-01 00:00 data
$ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet)
$ su
su: permission denied
```

How can I backup `/data` from this phone?

Comment: @Izzy I edited the question, but just to be sure, here are the answers: I do not have any custom ROM installed, and do not have root access. If there is a way to gain root access without overwriting the application data, that would probably be the answer to my question. As evidenced by the output, I can connect just fine via `adb shell`, but `adb backup` doesn't work as the device is running Android 2.3.5.

Comment: Looks like that device has an entry in our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575): [Galaxy SL GT i9003](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32461/16575). Please refer to that one for the rooting part. Apart from that: correct conclusion. `adb backup` was introduced with ICS, and without root you'll have no access to your apps' data below `/data`. Best would be a Nandroid backup, which you even could create via adb from your computer (see [Is there a way to do Nandroid backup directly to pc?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/16575)) root needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy the data by first [rooting the phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32461/how-to-root-galaxy-sl-gt-i9003-for-ddlf2). After routing, I can boot up the phone in recovery mode, connect via `adb shell`, and use `cat /dev/mmcblk0` / `cat /dev/block/stl10` to get the interesting data from the phone.