# Samsung Galaxy 2 stuck at start up. Can I recovery the phone or at least the data?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot, data-recovery, reboot, bootloader

My Samsung Galaxy 2 stuck every time when start up. It looks ok on the beginning, it shows "Samsung Galaxy S II ..." then change display to Vodafone logo then the shows word "samsung" and stuck here forever. It does not respond to any key after that. To shut it down I need to take the battery off.
My questions are if I can recovery the operational system or at least data from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a similar problem and shall update this answer as I find more information.

What [variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II#Variants) of Samsung Galaxy S II do you have?

These steps could help:

1. Fresh reboot by pulling battery, SIM card and any external SD card out for a while (some sources I have read say to wait over an hour).
2. Clear the cache partition (this is safe, no data loss):
   Hold <kbd>power</kbd>, <kbd>volume up</kbd> and <kbd>menu</kbd> simultaneously to boot the phone into recovery (for Samsung).
   Select `wipe cache partition` using the <kbd>volume up</kbd> and <kbd>volume down</kbd> keys, then press <kbd>menu</kbd>.
3. The [`boot-loop` tag information](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) contains further instructions.
4. Otherwise, [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59044/81471) indicated that it should be possible to [root the phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185) and recover data via the [Android Debug Bridge (ADB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#ADB): [these instructions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/89103/81471) should work for the Samsung Galaxy S II GT-i9100 but I have not yet tried them.