# Rooting Samsung Galaxy S II GT-i9100

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, linux

How does one root a Samsung Galaxy S II GT-i9100 (with its original Android 2.3 Gingerbread), preferably under Linux Mint?

This questions pertains specifically the GT-i9100 version (not GT-i9100G nor GT-i9100T, et cetera), which currently has no entry under the [rooting index](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185).

I am particularly looking for a rooting method which does not wipe the data on the phone, as [I am hoping to recover data afterwards](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89133/data-recovery-on-boot-looped-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-gt-i9100). I have an 8GB external SD card.

Comment: If you're that concerned about losing your data then BACKUP!!!! Better safe than sorry, I can't stress the importance of backups enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need the file http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1674014&d=1359080668 here and copy it to the external SD card (the one you connect to a slot in the phone)
Steps:

1. Save the file to external sd card
2. Open stock recovery (press power + vol up + home button)
3. Install zip from external sd card
4. Choose the file "CWM-SuperSU-v0.97.zip" from the SD card

Flash it and then reboot

Comment: Will this preserve my data? I should have specified in the question that I am intending to root the phone as part of a data recovery process. I shall edit the question.

Comment: Yes it will preserve your data, flashing a rooted kernel will not touch your data in any way, though the usual disclaimer about kittens applies :)

Comment: Am I correct in saying the linked attachment comes from [this forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/general/steps-rooting-gt-i9100-4-1-2-t2116549/)? If so, it mentions "4.1.2 firmwares": is this still applicable as I have 2.3 Gingerbread?
I'm just being overly cautious/paranoid as this is my first time rooting and I need to avoid data loss. Unfortunately I cannot boot the phone so thus cannot check Kernel or Build Number through the "About device" menu.

Comment: It should work fine. Recoveries don't change much in stock from version to version. The worst that will happen is that it will tell you its incompatible, but my (educated) guess is that it will work fine.

Comment: Just tried warsong's answer, using one of my old phones (exact match to the OP's. Android v2.3.3). The result of step 3 of warsong's answer is: `Finding update package... opening update package... Verifying update package... E:Failed to verify whole-file signature E:signature verification failed Installation aborted`. One difference is that I did a factory reset of the phone before attempting any of this.

Answer (score -1):

Root genius and iRoot, both of them are free to root your samsung galaxy phone. Rooting will write new data to your device.

Comment: Isn't "Root genius" a Windows-only solution?