# Rooting Samsung Galaxy S II GT-i9100 (follow on Q'n)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-recovery, boot, reboot

I'm a newbie to digging into Android this deep, so please bear with me. FYI I'm more familiar with PC's, with a smattering of the back office side of things from muddling along. So any response couched in familiar terms would be welcome.

I'm in the same situation as this: [Rooting Samsung Galaxy S II GT-i9100](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88717/rooting-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-gt-i9100/89103?newreg=37c10d82898241a5b78b6e8ff36e9bf1), which I've read along with the associated comments. Specifically I have notes in a notebook app which I'm very keen to recover. I have no idea where these apps actually store information and whether or not it's embedded in some way.

I gather following the advice given may/will remove/replace all the apps along with the 'kernel'(aka Operating System??)?  Will this process lose the data?

Critically I don't know if the data I'm after is considered 'my/your data' in the context of the response given.

Thnx

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75087/discussion-on-question-by-ian-rooting-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-gt-i9100-follow-on-q).